# Weird Ping response

Tags: networking, ping

When I ping `1.1.1.1` I receive this output:

```
C:\Users\user>ping 1.1.1.1

Pinging 1.1.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.201.1.114: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 10.201.1.114: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 10.201.1.114: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 10.201.1.114: TTL expired in transit.
```

As you see `10.201.1.114` is pinged instead with **TTL expired in transit.**!

Q1: Why?

When I ping `10.201.1.114`:

```
C:\Users\User>ping 10.201.1.114

Pinging 10.201.1.114 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.201.1.114: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=246
Reply from 10.201.1.114: bytes=32 time=129ms TTL=246
Reply from 10.201.1.114: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=246
Reply from 10.201.1.114: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=246
```

Q2: Why I receive another result?

And when I tracert the first IP (`1.1.1.1`):

```
C:\Users\Erb4h1m>tracert -d 1.1.1.1

Tracing route to 1.1.1.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.0.0.60
  2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.254.1
  3     4 ms     2 ms     7 ms  192.168.118.97
  4     2 ms     8 ms     3 ms  192.168.172.1
  5     2 ms     2 ms     3 ms  192.168.172.65
  6    11 ms     8 ms    17 ms  10.201.42.21
  7    42 ms    44 ms    47 ms  10.201.42.10
  8    42 ms    42 ms    53 ms  10.201.1.114
  9    34 ms    38 ms    43 ms  185.57.203.74
 10    41 ms    40 ms    47 ms  185.57.203.73
 11    42 ms    55 ms    49 ms  10.201.1.113
 12    77 ms    74 ms    77 ms  10.201.1.114
 13    69 ms    72 ms    77 ms  185.57.203.74
 14    80 ms    74 ms    76 ms  185.57.203.73
 15    77 ms    79 ms    78 ms  10.201.1.113
 16   120 ms   109 ms   110 ms  10.201.1.114
 17   107 ms   105 ms   117 ms  185.57.203.74
 18   110 ms   130 ms   109 ms  185.57.203.73
 19   127 ms   112 ms   109 ms  10.201.1.113
 20   152 ms   152 ms   144 ms  10.201.1.114
 21   137 ms   137 ms   138 ms  185.57.203.74
 22   146 ms   144 ms   144 ms  185.57.203.73
 23   144 ms   146 ms   145 ms  10.201.1.113
 24   184 ms   179 ms   182 ms  10.201.1.114
 25   173 ms   172 ms   171 ms  185.57.203.74
 26   180 ms   192 ms   181 ms  185.57.203.73
 27   180 ms   178 ms   187 ms  10.201.1.113
 28   214 ms   218 ms   231 ms  10.201.1.114
 29   209 ms   205 ms   205 ms  185.57.203.74
 30   214 ms   213 ms   219 ms  185.57.203.73

Trace complete.
```

Q3: Above, you see that my ping request passed the target IP (i.e `10.201.1.114`) six times (rows : 8,12,16,20,24,28)! Why?

Comment: "As you see 10.201.1.114 is pinged instead with TTL expired in transit.!". I disagree.  10.201.1.114 in somewhere in the path and it detects a TTL of 0, so it replies back because of that. It is not the target of the ICMP echo request.

Answer (score 1):

This question demonstrates a lack of fundamental understanding of TCP/IP.

I would recommend reading up on TTL:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live

and traceroute:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute

As for your actual "questions":

**Q1: Why?**

Because you are pinging an invalid ([Martian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_packet)) IP and the TTL is expiring in transit.

**Q2: Why I receive another result?**

Please refer to the first line of your tracert output.

**Q3: Above, you see that my ping request passed the target IP (i.e 10.201.1.114) six times (rows : 8,12,16,20,24,28)! Why?**

You are tracing an invalid ([Martian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_packet)) destination. Behaviour regarding invalid ([Martian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_packet)) addresses is undefined.

Comment: How is `1.1.1.1` an invalid IP address?

Comment: @DanielB: Look it up: http://wq.apnic.net/apnic-bin/whois.pl

(descr: Research prefix for APNIC Labs remarks: Address blocks listed with this contact  are withheld from general use and are only routed briefly for passive testing)

Comment: That doesn’t make it an invalid IP address. It just means it usually isn’t reachable.

Comment: @DanielB: Perhaps we have differing understandings of the word "invalid". In this case it means it is intended to be *never* usable. When it *is* reachable it shouldn't be reachable by *you* anyway, so that is moot.

Comment: No, on the contrary. It’s very well defined what’s a valid destination IP address and what’s not. 1.1.1.1 is a valid destination IP address. Reachability is not a concern.

Comment: @DanielB: Then we clearly have differing understandings of the word "invalid". I consider martian addresses to be invalid, as does the IETF.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26397/discussion-between-daniel-b-and-qasdfdsaq).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, this segment repeats:

```
  8    42 ms    42 ms    53 ms  10.201.1.114
  9    34 ms    38 ms    43 ms  185.57.203.74
 10    41 ms    40 ms    47 ms  185.57.203.73
 11    42 ms    55 ms    49 ms  10.201.1.113
```

That means there’s a [routing loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_loop_problem) involving these four hops. This is a configuration error on one of these hosts. Because each hop decreases the TTL field by one, the packet is rejected eventually.